# How to set if a computer in AD is assigned to a particular user?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, rename, workstation-management

We have computers that are renamed every time a new employee shows up.  This causes a lot of work unnecessary work for the IT department.  Now while it isn't always true 100% of the time that each user MUST use the same computer all the time, it's good for us to know which machine a user is on in general.

So when using Active Directory to determine which machine a user is on most of the time, what property should I set?

I've looked and in computers and as far as I can tell, there is `Owner` and `Description`.

Description can only be searched for using the AD module for Powershell, and while `Owner` can be searched using the `Find Computers` dialog I don't actually know where to set it in the properties of a computer in `Active Directory Users and Computers`; I also don't know what other implications there might be for using the `Owner` property, or if it can be set using `Powershell` for a particular machine.

So what is the correct way to figure out what user is "assigned" to a machine without renaming the machines every time an employee is replaced?

Comment: I'm 99% sure *everything* in AD can be set and searched in Powershell, it's just some attributes/properties are easier to set than others. I haven't figured out a sure-fire way to do this myself, and at my last job we renamed computers, but it was cumbersome. I think you'll find updating AD constantly is less cumbersome but still not great. We currently have an almost-solution of using Spiceworks to scan the network and tell us who the last logged in user of a computer is.

Comment: Yeah, but our Spiceworks machine is slow when it scans; it takes all day.

Comment: Yes, Spiceworks is not real-time, but you can go through the inventory of everything previously scanned while it is scanning. If you just added/changed a computer, you can scan that individual IP which takes just a couple minutes. Like I said, it's an almost-solution, but not perfect. SCCM might be better, but it's also way expensive (at least for our budget).